# Kineticjs: ADD rect, REMOVE rect, then ADD AGAIN not working mouseover

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, kineticjs

I had an issue adding, removing and re-adding a kineticjs in a layer.

It stops to work the mouseevents after the re-add. Example:

```
object.on("mouseover", function() { console.log("mouseover"); });
layer.add(object);
object.remove();
layer.add(object);
```

Here is a recreation of the problem:

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/VDr6z/)

Comment: recreate the problem in a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use a factory method instead: http://jsfiddle.net/VDr6z/1/

```
var obj = {
    rect : undefined,
    rectstored : function(){
        return new Kinetic.Rect({
            x : 10,
            y : 10,
            width : 30,
            height : 30,
            fill : "rgb(140,140,140)"
        });
    }
};
```

You'll also want to manage the rect:

```
$("#create").click(function(){
    if (obj.rect) return; // don't create more than one rect.

    var rect = obj.rectstored();  // create new rect

    rect.on("mouseover", function(){
        $("#console").html("mouse is over");
    });
    rect.on("mouseout", function(){
        $("#console").html("mouse is out");
    });

    obj.rect = rect;

    layer.add(rect);
    layer.draw();
});

$("#delete").click(function(){
    if (!obj.rect) return;  // exit if there is no rect

    obj.rect.remove();
    delete obj.rect;        // delete reference to rect

    layer.draw();
});​
```

Answer (score 0):

In case you do not need to delete the object, just hide and unhide object can solve it for you

```
var javascriptobj = {
    rectstored : new Kinetic.Rect({
        x : 10,
        y : 10,
        width : 30,
        height : 30,
        fill : "rgb(140,140,140)"
    })
};

var stage = new Kinetic.Stage({
    container : 'canvas',
    width : 120,
    height : 120,
});

var layer = new Kinetic.Layer();
stage.add(layer);
    layer.add(javascriptobj.rectstored);
    javascriptobj.rectstored.hide();

$("#create").click(function(){
    javascriptobj.rectstored.on("mouseover", function(){
        $("#console").html("mouse is over");
    });
    javascriptobj.rectstored.on("mouseout", function(){
        $("#console").html("mouse is out");
    });

    javascriptobj.rectstored.show();
        layer.draw();
});

$("#delete").click(function(){
    javascriptobj.rectstored.hide();
    layer.draw();
});​
```

Comment: This could be an excellent solution, but the doubt about it is if when the count of rects comes hight (about 1 million) it will preserve the stability and performance. It is a part of screen render and I'm showing just 300 rects at a time. I will try this. Thank you.

Comment: This doesn't solve my problem. As I said, when the rects count comes high, the performance becomes vary poor.

Comment: so you need to remove all the 300 rects at one go and then recreate them again?? Well better make them part of a group and hide the entire group instead of each individual object. Believe that solves it!